# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, angular9, angular-observable

I am getting the following error

> Argument of type '(user: User) => void' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type '(value: User, index: number) => ObservableInput'. Type
>   'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.

```
 getCurrentUserDb()
  {
    return this.login.authState.pipe(
                        switchMap(user=>{
                          return this.serviceUsers.getUserByuid(user.uid);
                        }),
                        map(user=>{
                          return user;
                        })
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you were trying to map the results from the inner observable (`map(user => ...`) but instead applied it to the source. If so, try the following

```js
getCurrentUserDb(): Observable<any> {
  return this.login.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      return this.serviceUsers.getUserByuid(user.uid).pipe(
        map(user => {
          return user;
        })
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is `this.serviceUsers.getUserByuid(user.uid)` returning an Observable? It looks like you're trying to `switchMap` to a void.